# Formating big numbers in Java

Tags: java

I have an edittext with a maxlength

My question is...

How can I display the value of a bigger number than the maxlenght like the windows calc??

Example:

```
1.34223423423434e+32
```

I want this with the edittext maxlength

EDIT: I want this for display and store numbers without having problems with math operations if it's possible

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class (or [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), for non-integers) is for.

These classes store numbers with arbitrary precision, and allow for standard arithmetic operations.  You can get the exact value of the number as a string, and then format that as you wish (e.g. trimming the length).

(Note that while it may seem like you can use these classes with a [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) instance, this is not recommended as accuracy will be silently lost if the number doesn't fit into a `double`.)

Here's an example of using it:

```
// Create a BigDecimal from the input text
final String numStr = editText.getValue(); // or whatever your input is
final BigDecimal inputNum = new BigDecimal(numStr);

// Alternatievly you could pass a double into the BigDecimal constructor,
// though this might already lose precison - e.g. "1.1" cannot be represented
// exactly as a double.  So the String constructor is definitely preferred,
// especially if you're using Double.parseDouble somewhere "nearby" as then
// it's a drop-in replacement.

// Do arithmetic with it if needed:
final BigDecimal result = inputNum.multiply(new BigDecimal(2));

// Print it out in standard scientific format
System.out.println(String.format("%e", result));

// Print it out in the format you gave, i.e. scientific with 14dp
System.out.println(String.format("%.14e", result));

// Or do some custom formatting based on the exact string value of the number
final String resultStr = result.toString();
System.out.println("It starts with " + result.subString(0, 3) + "...");
```

I'm not sure *exactly* what format you wanted for output, but whatever it is you should be able to manage it with BigDecimals as the backing store.

Comment: but how can I implement that? i'm using double values right now... can you put an example??

Comment: Jesus why don't you use the links provided by @AndrzejDoyle or you can easily google search it to get tutorials....

Comment: @Jesus I've edited a brief example into my question showing how to construct, multiply, and output a BigDecimal.